# Contar numeros repetidos en una lista

Tags: vb.net

debo contar la cantidad de números repetidos que pueden haber en una lista. Ingreso números por teclados y al finalizar la carga, los números cargados los paso a una lista.

Esto que tengo esta funcionando mal.

```
**Function NumerosRepetidos(ByRef listaNumeros As List(Of Byte), ByRef numero As Byte) As Long

        listaNumeros.Add(numero) 

        Dim i, x As Long

        x = -1

        For i = 0 To listaNumeros.Count - 1

            If numero = listaNumeros(i) Then
                x += 1
            End If

            Console.WriteLine("El numero: {0}", numero, "se repitio " & x & " " & "veces.")

        Next


        Return numero

    End Function**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que buscas lo puedes hacer con una simple instrucción de `LINQ`, lo cual se usa importando la librería `System.Linq`. Te quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
Private Function NumerosRepetidos(ByVal listaNumeros As List(Of Integer), ByVal numero As Integer) As Long
    return listaNumeros.Where(Function(x) x = numero).Count()
End Function
```

Puedes probar el código en el siguiente [enlace](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3mheqj).